# Efficient way of describing a tuple in Javascript, JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Consider the following use case:

- an AV Receiver sends me a status message : SURR0004
- I can easily decode that into status:SURR, value:4
- In my display app, I want to show a user friendly string, such as "STEREO"
- In my display app, which uses generic commands, the command that is equivalent to the receiver created and received value of 4 might be ST.
- So, I need a lookup array (stored in a JSON file) that offers me the array of variable maps in the SURR category. Each array should include the Receiver Code (i.e. 4), the Generic Command (i.e. ST) and the display text (i.e. "STEREO").
- There might be 50 elements in this array alone! So I need an approach to expressing them with the least overhead (in both file size and processing terms).

One approach could be JSON that looks like the below. But 50 of these elements gets unwieldy fast! And there are 6 or 7 other categories like SURR!

```
 "SURR": [
      {
        "deviceCode": "1",
        "stdCode": "STE",
        "display": "STEREO EXTENDED"
      },
      {
        "deviceCode": "4",
        "stdCode": "ST",
        "display": "STEREO"
      }]
```

Another approach might be the below. And while this saves space, it also lacks readability and is easily screwed up in the authoring.

```
    "SURR": 
    [
        "mapValues": 
        [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            ...
        ],
        "commandValues": 
        [
            STE,
            DD,
            DTX,
            NIGHT,
            ST,
            ...
        ],
        "mapDisplayValues": 
        [
            "SOMETHING",
            "DOLBY DIGITAL",
            "ANALOG",
            "SOMETHING ELSE",
            "STEREO",
            ...
        ]
    ]
```

There must be another approach that is both easy to read and understand as well as being efficient?

A simple array?

```
[
  {"1", "STEX", "STEREO CYCLE"}
  {"9", "ST", "STEREO"}
]
```

Would love to get some thoughts on the best way of organizing the data and why!

s.

Comment: `[["1", "STEX", "STEREO LIFECYCLE"], ...]`

Comment: How large is the object in the nicely readable form you showed with 8 categories  * 50 elements and 3 fields. ~30KB? Is there any reason to introduce any of the additional challenges of compact data when you know the size of the file you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your off-the-cuff suggestion is not valid JSON:

```
[
  {"1", "STEX", "STEREO CYCLE"}
  {"9", "ST", "STEREO"}
]
```

A JSON object consists of name/value pairs, not just values. You could just make them arrays, though:

```
[
  ["1", "STEX", "STEREO CYCLE"]
  ["9", "ST", "STEREO"]
]
```

---

As far as your other concerns, JSON is easily the most-compact format that is readily accessible to a javascript application. However, if you're worried about storage or transfer limitations, you can always serialize the data into a plainer text format, like tab- or comma-delimited text, which is easily marshalled into more-useful structures at runtime (and for which you can find solid libraries). If your example data is representative, that could account for maybe 10% size savings.

Most JS engines are extremely fast these days: you can easily iterate over an array of 10k items in a few ms. Unless you're writing for some kind of underpowered embedded device, it will make no difference. Even in that scenario, an array of a couple hundred items will be effectively free to access. However, if you're really worried, you can always use a hash table instead of an array, for direct access rather than always having to search:

```
{
  "1": { "code": "STEX", "dsp": "STEREO CYCLE" },
  "9": { "code": "ST",   "dps": "STEREO" }
}
```

Direct access obviously eliminates the need to iterate over the entire collection. But again, unless you're building for an extremely underpowered device or JS engine, none of this will make any difference.

---

Badly structured data tends to encourage badly-factored business logic and display code. My advice would be to choose the data structures that reflect the data domain as accurately as possible, rather than over-indexing on performance constraints from the get-go.

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth

If you're worried about typos at authoring time, find a tool online, or build it as plain text and then write a one-time conversion script, or just build the structure in the browser console and then export it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take an object with the status message as key.

The advantage is the comnpact structure and it is easy to maintain because all informations are at the same place in the objects.

```
{
    SURR0001: {
        deviceCode: "1",
        stdCode: "STE",
        display: "STEREO EXTENDED"
    },
    SURR0004: {
        deviceCode: "4",
        stdCode: "ST",
        display: "STEREO"
    }
}
```